# Javascript sort array in custom order

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array like `[c, a, b]`. The array is dynamic, and the possible values for array are **a, b, c, d, and e**. And I want to sort the array in a specific order like **b,d,c,a,e**.

ie.
My desired output is `[b, d, a]` in this case

If input is `[e, b]` the output is `[b, e]` like that. Is there any single method for this?

Comment: `custom order`? or do you mean `random order`? Is there any pattern?

Comment: Why you need above kind of sorting. Please specify a reason and multiple test cases.

Comment: @Mukyuu yes random order

Comment: You can check the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a callback to an array sort function (c.f. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Syntax )